# Unable to drop database in PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am unable to delete a database called postgres. Here is my code from trying to drop it in the command line in Git-Bash:

```
default=# DROP DATABASE postgres;

ERROR:  database "postgres" is being accessed by other users

DETAIL:  There are 2 other sessions using the database.
```

I am the only person using the database. Also when I right click on the postgres database in pgAdmin, the delete/drop option does not appear. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have the answer here [Is it safe to delete the 3 default databases created during a PostgreSQL install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134848/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-3-default-databases-created-during-a-postgresql-install)

Comment: Great! Thank you for this